# unable to make a block responsive using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make this responsive on mobile screen

```
   <div class="row well">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/450X300/DD66DD/EE77EE" class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="caption">
                             <h3>Plot 1</h3>
    
                            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>  <a href="#">Electronic City</a>
    
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Rs. 1400000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Land</td>
                            <td>7 acres</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Plots</td>
                            <td>154</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Avaliable Plots</td>
                            <td>15</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" value="ENQUIRY">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
      
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/450X300/DD66DD/EE77EE" class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="caption">
                             <h3>Plot 1</h3>
    
                            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>  <a href="#">Electronic City</a>
    
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Rs. 1400000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Land</td>
                            <td>7 acres</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Plots</td>
                            <td>154</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Avaliable Plots</td>
                            <td>15</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" value="ENQUIRY">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/450X300/DD66DD/EE77EE" class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="caption">
                             <h3>Plot 1</h3>
    
                            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>  <a href="#">Electronic City</a>
    
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Rs. 1400000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Land</td>
                            <td>7 acres</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Plots</td>
                            <td>154</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Avaliable Plots</td>
                            <td>15</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" value="ENQUIRY">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <img src="//placehold.it/450X300/DD66DD/EE77EE" class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="caption">
                             <h3>Plot 1</h3>
    
                            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>  <a href="#">Electronic City</a>
    
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Rs. 1400000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Land</td>
                            <td>7 acres</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Total Plots</td>
                            <td>154</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Avaliable Plots</td>
                            <td>15</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" value="ENQUIRY">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
    </div>
```

view on desktop , this is fine
[image]

view on small screen , the design is getting compressed

And i want to show single plot record in a row , not two as shown below

How to make it responsive in small screen?

i am using bootstrap 3 for this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col-xs-` is specifically for mobile phones. And making it `col-xs-12` will make it take full width.

Update your columns

from

`<div class="col-sm-3">`

to

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">`

[image]

Comment: @chaitanyaKoripella updated. sorry didn't saw you already have `col-xs-6` class. I have removed that.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKoripella you sure? I checked your demo and it isn't updated. Change it from `col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-6` to `col-xs-12 col-sm-3`